# How to fully integrate in bb10 hub like WhatsApp?

Tags: blackberry-10

The latest version of whatsapp was integrated in bb hub. when click on message item for whatsapp in hub, will open a card UI that can send and receive message.
but it still able to send and receive message when I close whatsapp, how to achieve it?
Card and app has own process and context, need across-process communication(card communication with application)?

Answer (score 1):

It has been reported, and widely held, though I have never seen any official documentation it is none the less probably true that the WhatsApp developers were given early access to Hub integration APIs that are not yet widely available to third party developers.

Comment: I know that BlackBerry 10 not yet widely allows third party developers to use hub integration apis, but I have some issues. when click on message item for whatsapp in hub, will open a card UI that can send and receive message even user close whatsapp. because the card has own process, so the app should run as a background service, how to achieve communication between app and card?

Comment: Read the documentation on cards, you will find many of your assumptions are incorrect: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/cards.html

Comment: thanks, but I still don't know whatsapp how do it, you can try to use whatsapp.

Comment: Really? You want to rip-off how another developer is making a product, and you want me to reverse engineer it for you? No thank you.

Comment: no,you've misunderstanding. I just discuss with you that how to achieve the effect like whatsapp. I want to integrate my app to hub in the future, in case the BlackBerry support access to Hub integration APIS.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good deal of information out there now for anybody looking to find it.  There's a handy page on [BlackBerry Hub Integration](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/uds.html) for C and C++ (native) developers.  You basically need to use the [UDS (Unified Data Source) Library](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.uds.lib_ref/topic/overview.html) to open a connection to the BlackBerry Hub and register your app with the Hub.

This [page](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/uds_using_the_uds_apis.html) has a lot of example code related to Hub integration.  The basic steps are:

1. Open a connection to the Hub.
2. Register your app with the Hub.
3. Retrieve your service ID via the UDS.
4. Add an account.
5. Add and manipulate inbox list items on the Hub.

Comment: Yes, certainly two years after the question was first asked the landscape has changed. I doubt the OP is even still on SO though.

Comment: it helped me, another two years later ;)